# Table Filter greater than and blanks at the same time

Tags: excel, vba, filter, listobject

I currently have an excel table which I want to filter with 2 Criteria simultaneously.

I want the table to be presented with a ">=" Criteria and with a "<>" Criteria in the same filed.

Since the table is big I want to limit the rows to be shown (Criteria ">=") and, on the other hand, to give the blank cells of the same filed as input (Criteria "<>").

The code I wrote follows:

```
Sub Filter()

Dim tbl As ListObject
Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("PiPeLine_Table")

    tbl.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    tbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=">=202100000", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<>"

End Sub
```

Though my table shows like just the Criteria1 had been applied:

Field 7 represents the colored column.

Last cell with value is the one shown (202200205).

After this cell should the blank cells show.

[image]

Pretty sure I'm doing a basic mistake or missing something really basic but can't figure out what it is.

Hope some of you can help me out.

Rafa

Answer (score 1):

When using `Operator:=xlAnd`, you are asking for both conditions to be true. So `202200205` is both `">=202100000"` and `"<>"`, but a blank is just `"<>"`.

Change it to `Operator:=xlOr`. So if either condition is true the match will be shown.

Comment: Thanks Damian, I knew it should be the silliest thing ever form my side.